# I don't find any error.this code doing well.update my data perfectly.but 1 error is showing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
            $updatedate=$_POST['date'];
            $updateday=$_POST['day'];
            $updateplace=$_POST['place'];
            $updatehighlight=$_POST['highlight'];
            $updatediscription=$_POST['discription'];
            $sqlupdate="UPDATE $tableselect SET entrydate='$updatedate',day='$updateday',place='$updateplace',highlight='$updatehighlight',discription='$updatediscription' WHERE id ='$getid'";
            $sqlquery=mysqli_query($db,$sqlupdate);
            if (!mysqli_query($db,$sqlquery)) {
                    echo "error " .$sqlquery. "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
                }
        }
```

it showing this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: comma spacing is weird

Comment: So where exactly does `$getid` come from?

Comment: it still giving same massage.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: $getid is my row id.it's come another page where user click to update data of this row..i echo it and this id result fine i think..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Real simple, you're running the query function twice, that's why you're getting `1`.

- 1 being boolean TRUE.
- [(MySQL) Boolean Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html)

So

```
$sqlquery=mysqli_query($db,$sqlupdate);
            if (!mysqli_query($db,$sqlquery)) {...}
```

needs to be changed to just

```
$sqlquery=mysqli_query($db,$sqlupdate);
            if(!$sqlquery){...}
```

The first gets executed, and the (if)`!` operator will also trigger the query function since it was TRUE, as in "(if)not failing".

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

> *"For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return **TRUE**."*

Parametrize your query also, you're open to an SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: @chris85 Yeah just saw that now. I made another slight edit "about the 1".